# Analog of _mm256_cmp_epi32_mask for AVX2

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, intrinsics, avx2

I have 8 32-bit integers packed into `__m256i` registers. Now I need to compare corresponding 32-bit values in two registers. Tried

```
__mmask8 m = _mm256_cmp_epi32_mask(r1, r2, _MM_CMPINT_EQ);
```

that flags the equal pairs. That would be great, but I got an "illegal instruction" exception, likely because my processor doesn't support AVX512.

Looking for an analogous intrinsic to quickly get indexes of the equal pairs.

Found a work-around (there is no `_mm256_movemask_epi32`); is the cast legal here?

```
__m256i diff = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(m1, m2);
__m256 m256 = _mm256_castsi256_ps(diff);
int i = _mm256_movemask_ps(m256);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `cast` intrinsics are just a reinterpret of the bits in the YMM registers, it's 100% legal and yes the asm you want the compiler to emit is `vpcmpeqd` / `vmovmaskps`.

Or if you can deal with each bit being repeated 4 times, `vpmovmskb` also works, `_mm256_movemask_epi8`.  e.g. if you just want to test for any matches (`i != 0`) or all-matches (`i == 0xffffffff`) you can avoid using a `ps` instruction on an integer result which might cost 1 extra cycle of bypass latency in the critical path.

But if that would cost you extra instructions to e.g. scale by 4 after using `_mm_tzcnt_u32` to find the element index instead of byte index of the first 1, then use the `_ps` movemask.  The extra instruction will definitely cost latency, and a slot in the pipeline for throughput.

Comment: Thank you very much! Greatly appreciate your time. BTW, most of my googling for AVX, asm, optimization, etc. point to YOUR answer here on SO :)  Any chance you can look at my code review post? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/253761/optimizing-bit-matching-performance-using-avx-compiler-intrinsic